# activerecord in-memory shared cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, jruby, rails-activerecord, in-memory-database

Is possible to use the "shared cache" of sqlite3 through activerecord? 
(see: http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)

I use activerecord standalone (without rails) in a JRuby Swing App, with some Worker-Threads involved. Problem: ONLY the main thread can access the data, since every thread rebuilds a new in-memory DB. So i get just

[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: insert_model_name)

from everywhere, except the main thread. Is there a workaround or did I miss something?
(i use the latest versions of jruby, java, and the gems)

Thanks in advance!

Database-Config so far: https://gist.github.com/4482423

**UPDATE:** Minimal script to illustrate the problem. It runs well under Linux but not in WIndows 7: https://gist.github.com/4483617

Comment: Can you post your database.yml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following token works well:
`"file::memory:?cache=shared"`
Also, check your SQLite version, it should be at least 3.7.13 to support this feature.

Comment: this stopped working, it now creates a file with that name :(

Comment: @grosser did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: no, did not figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your sqlite was built, configuring the database name with a URI token alone may not be sufficient: The default build configuration since at least [v3.38.2](https://github.com/sqlite/sqlite/commit/b48c0d59faf3bfd3e1fc0c3bed5557816c36cb7e) is not to parse URI tokens (`SQLITE_USE_URI` defaults to 0).

You can enable the shared cache behavior in your ActiveRecord configuration by passing [flags](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/c_open_autoproxy.html) that enable URI parsing and using the `"file::memory:?cache=shared"` token from earlier answers.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :adapter => "sqlite3",
                                    :database => "file::memory:?cache=shared",
                                    :flags => 70 # SQLite3::Constants::Open::READWRITE | CREATE | URI
```